# Custom permalinks structure

Tags: categories, permalinks, customization

I would like to have this structure:

```
www.mysite.com/2013
```

(must show all posts of 2013)

```
www.mysite.com/my-category/2013
```

(must show all posts of 2013 and of category "my-category")

```
www.mysite.com/my-category/my-tag/
```

(must show all posts of category "my-category" and of tag "my-tag")

```
www.mysite.com/my-category/
```

(must show all posts of category "my-category")

```
www.mysite.com/my-category/title-post
```

(must show the post)

How can I do it?

Comment: Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to recommend you to get acquainted with [The Rewrite API: The Basics](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-the-basics/) article. I do believe that you will be able to change your permalinks structure in the way you want, if you read and learn it carefully.